# Java ArrayList toArray avoid copying

Tags: java, performance, arraylist

Is there any way to get an ArrayList's inner array without having it being duplicated?

I have a function which takes a normal java array as input, which I want to call with the contents of an ArrayList. The problem is that I'm going to be calling it very frequently and making copies every time would cause performance issues.

Comment: How do you know that an ArrayList has an "inner array"?  It could be a linked list or any other structure.

Comment: @HotLicks: A linked list would make O(1) random access tricky...

Comment: @HotLicks really? what does the name `ArrayList` imply?

Comment: Imply, and guarantee, are different things. Yes, ArrayList is generally implemented on top of arrays -- but it may not be a single array; it could be multiple, with modulo addressing selecting which is accessed. Abstraction means you don't know, and don't need to know, as long as the behavior matches the definition.

Comment: Why don't you just copy once?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth The contents and size of the array will change over time

Comment: @Henry - The name "ArrayList" implies that it may be accessed similarly to an array.  Has nothing to do with the internal structure.

Comment: Today, with that particular JVM an array is used internally.

Comment: It is quite conceivable that an implementation would do the array in parts, eg, to facilitate efficient expansion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
static Object[] getBackingArray(ArrayList<?> arrayList) {
    try {
        Field elementData = ArrayList.class.getDeclaredField("elementData");
        elementData.setAccessible(true);
        return (Object[]) elementData.get(arrayList);
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException | IllegalAccessException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Note that you need to do this again each time the array list gets resized. Then again, this is brittle and awful and you should never do it in the first place.

---

If you need random access while processing your data, but the number of elements can grow and you can't put an upper bound on that, then `ArrayList` is conceptually the right tool for the job. In that case, what you should do is refactor your processing code to work with `Lists`. A random access implementation like `ArrayList` gives you everything arrays do, so I don't see any problems with that in principle.

Comment: Brittle and awful and may not work in any other release of Java and... yeah. The querent did say "any way", and this may be a way, so it's a correct answer. I'm still not decided whether I can up-vote it in good conscience.

Comment: In this case this is unique solution, even he breaks `Incapacitation`. So +1.

Comment: Note that this (horrible) scheme does not return the size of the array.

Comment: @HotLicks, what do you mean? It returns the array itself. You can get its size as you normally would, via the `length` field. If you need the actual number of elements in the `ArrayList`, you can just call `size()` on that.

Answer (score 2):

Write you own array list implementation with public access to the backing array, or use one from any existing Java Collections lib, for example [`ObjectArrayList<E>`](http://fastutil.di.unimi.it/docs/index.html?it/unimi/dsi/fastutil/objects/ObjectArrayList.html) from [fastutil](http://fastutil.dsi.unimi.it/) has method `E[] elements()`. Yes, that's a bit odd to carry dependency for a single class, but if you are paying attention to performance, you could find primitive specializations of collections useful.

Answer (score 1):

Not that I know of. However, there's nothing saying you can't create your own implementation of List which is wrapped around an exposed Array. Thread-safety and mutability -- and the fact that the association would be lost if further appends to the List forced it to reallocate the array -- would be issues you'd have to deal with, but there's no reason you couldn't make it work.

That's the nice thing about interfaces -- if one implementation doesn't have the characteristics you need, you can create another.